# Something happened and this app couldn't be installed

Tags: windows-8

> Something happened and this app couldn't be installed.
>
> Please Try Again. Error Code: 0x800700b7.

I got this message while trying to upgrade an app in my new Windows 8 PC.

What is the fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this message when trying to run an app from a non-admin account on a new Windows 8 PC.  Internet searches reveal various suggestions, but for me **it seems to have resolved itself after a few hours and multiple reboots**.

You shouldn't expect to buy a new Windows PC and use it right away.  It will take several hours and several reboots before all of the initial updates are complete.

I suspect that many people have and will encounter this problem.

Comment: After a couple of years and several/various attempts I would suggest the following generalization of the above rule: **It is a very bad idea to expect anything on Windows 8 to work on the first try.**  If you are preparing for something important and timely, you better get it *completely* setup well in advance.