# Windows 8.1 cannot detect HDMI audio on older display

Tags: audio, windows-8.1, hdmi

My Windows 8.1 PC does not recognize my old HDMI monitor as an audio playback device.  Everything was working fine with a newer monitor, but when I switched to the older monitor, I got no sound.  I have booted Ubuntu 14.04.1 on the same computer/monitor and audio playback works fine with that.

If I click on the sound-disabled icon in the Notification Area, Windows analyzes the problem, and offers this sage advice:

```
Plug in the speaker, headset or headphone.
```

With the new monitor, I see "Intel(R) Display Audio" listed as the Default Device for Sound Playback, but with the old monitor, this isn't in the list (even if I enable "Show Disabled Devices" and "Show Disconnected Devices").

To summarize:

```
Works: Windows 8.1 with new monitor
Does not work: Windows 8.1 with old monitor
Works: Ubuntu 14.04.1 with old monitor
```

My PC hardware is: HP Pavilion Mini Desktop - 300-020

Comment: I guess this sounds like a bug report at this point.  I have seen several similar issues on other sites, but nothing helpful on superuser.  I would like to know if there is a fix, but this post may also be useful to let others know that their HDMI problems may be related to the TV/monitor -- not just the PC/drivers.

Comment: I just had the same problem with totally different hardware (and this time Windows 10), a setup which I'm pretty sure has worked previously.  My comment [here](http://superuser.com/a/610985/114579) is as true now as ever.  In this case, I eventually got it to work by a random sequence of rebooting, unplugging, and re-plugging.